# How to set sessions of the page before sending it through a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, security, session

I have the following case but i don't know how to do it .

I have a page say [`page1.aspx`] this page have a button in the event click of this button i call a method in web service , this method need a url as a param , every thing goes okay and the receiver ,receive the `url` ,but when clicks on that link ,it redirects to the `login page` instead of the sent page !! How to open the sent page which has sessions in a secure manner ?

```
 protected void SendNotification(int StateSerial)
        {
            DataTable dt = Utilities.GetStateUsers(StateSerial, taskCode);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string message = Session["TransDes"].ToString().Trim();
                string sender = Session["send"].ToString().Trim();
                string sys_code = "SM" + "|" + taskCode.ToString();
                string sys_name = Task.GetTask(taskCode).Rows[0]["task_name"].ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string emp_num = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    string serial = taskCode.ToString() + "|" + obj.TransSerial + "|" + obj.TransYear;


                    }
                    string URL_inbox = "https://..../Page1.aspx?TCode=" + taskCode + "&TransSerial=" + obj.TransSerial + "&TransYear=" + obj.TransYear + "&mainCode=" + obj.MainCode + "&year=" + obj.Year + "&MCode=" + obj.MainCode + "&DYear=" + obj.Year + "&AR=1";
                    Service1 noti = new Service1();
                    string res = noti.sendNotification(emp_num, message, URL_inbox, sender, serial, sys_code, sys_name);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Now the user receive the `URL_inbox` but when clicks on it it redirects to the `login page` instead

because the following code is in the page load of `Page1.aspx`

```
 if (Session["emp_num"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["emp_num"].ToString()))
            {
                emp_numb = int.Parse(Session["emp_num"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://..../LoginPage.aspx");
            }
```

How to handle this problem in secure manner ?